# Hidden UINavigationBar appearing on becomeFirstResponder (UIKeyboard appears)

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios8, uinavigationbar, uikeyboard

In iOS8 I have a `UIViewController` in which I have set

`[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];`

in `viewDidAppear`.

However in this same UIViewController I am triggering the keyboard using `becomeFirstResponder`. It seems that the hidden state of the *navigationBar* is ignored since it suddenly animates into the view when the keyboard appears.

Setting `self.navigationController.hidesBarsWhenKeyboardAppears` to true causes a brief animation toggle which is not desirable in the current case.

Has anyone come across this? Is there any new API to tell the navigationBar to *stay* hidden regardless?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having a similar issue: my custom navigation bar blinks off, then back on, then stays hidden when keyboard is shown, even though I have set it to hidesBarsWhenKeyboardAppears = NO.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS8 there are a lot of nifty features regarding the navigationController, one of them is the new gesture properties like `navigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe`. In our application some UIViewControllers hide the navigation bar, whilst others don't.

The problem was that even though we where hidding the navigationController, we where not resetting that property, causing a lot of confusion.

So if you see any quircky behaviour with the visibility of the `navigationController.navigationBar` make sure you are re-setting all the necessary properties accross views.